# My new Oxygen Sensor package does not include copper anti-seize

Tags: o2-sensor

My new Oxygen Sensor package does not include copper anti-seize.
I know that is is a good practice, and most S2 sensors come with an anti-seize paste.

I have this anti-seize that I use for my brake. Can I use it when I install my new O2 sensor?

[image]

**Answer:**

Many thanks to the responses below, it turned out that NTK model that I bought comes with the anti-seize applied to it. I should have checked that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the thread? MAny new sensors come with the anti-seize already applied. Copper with glass beads is best, but nickel is better than nothing.

Comment: No, I did not open the older O2 sensor, because I might decide to return this sensor that I have based on response to this question.

Comment: Should I invest on Copper anti-seize if it becomes usefull with other repairs?

Comment: @AllanXu you need to check the threads on the new one, **not** the old one...

Comment: Regardsless, is Copper anti-seize used in many applications, so does it worth buying a bottle?

Comment: If using an after-market copper anti-seize product, make sure that the packaging confirms that it is Sensor-Safe.